# Inconsistent results with AllenNLP Reading Comprehension

Tags: allennlp

We're seeing strange behavior with Reading Comprehension. Given the following people (names redacted) and their roles and contact numbers:

[image]

Asking RC for PersonAfname's number results in 4444, which is correct. It also correctly returns 3333 for PersonBfname's number. But when we ask for PersonCfname's number, it returns 4444 instead of 5555. What's up?

https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension/bidaf-elmo/s/what-is-perscfnames-number/Z8Z6J4A9D9

Comment: How large was the corpus/training set which you used to build your model?  Models built on very small training sets can have quirks.

Comment: This is using the demo functionality on the AllenNLP site. I'm not sure how it was trained.

Answer (score 0):

Reading comprehension models aren't perfect, but when I change the query from `PersCfname's` to `PersonCfname's`, it returns 5555.